# Angular html5Mode with ui-router and browserify

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, browserify

First time using browserify and module exports with Angular, and my usual setup for html5Mode is not working.

**app.js**

```
.config(function myAppConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
    ...
     <base href="/">
</head>
```

**What the above code is doing wrong...**

The routing works until the app is refreshed, and then the page assets disappear. Also if an in-correct url is given the app won't redirect to '/' like I'm intending.

Any thoughts/solutions?

**Update**: I'm having the same issue with and without the `.htaccess` that is rewriting the `/index.html` from the url, so I kinda thought that it wasn't related to the web server. If you think that it might be related to the web server, here is the `.htaccess`:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```